# How to flexibly use and replace std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr or raw pointer in C++ code?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Here's my meaning. Many times When I start a new program, I can't decide beforehand whether to use `std::shared` or `std::unique_ptr` or raw pointer to some C++ object. From performance perspective, I know `shared_ptr` has more penalty than `unique_ptr`, and sometimes raw pointer is better than `unique_ptr`.

In my recent project, team members all use `shared_ptr` no matter whether its wrapped object has multiple owners or not. It seems that `shared_ptr` is much safer to them, so they use it arbitrarily. However, to my experience, many objects needn't shared_ptr, when we realize that and refactor the code later, it's very likely that many API declarations need to be changed, which is not good.

So I reflex on this, and want to ask: Is there a way to decrease this refactoring cost ? Maybe we should design a wrapper object which may wrap shared_ptr, or unique_ptr, or raw pointer, and later when we realize we need to change the underlying structure, we only modify the wrapper. No changes to other API. Is that possible ? Anyone who try to do this ?

Comment: You are right to hesitate to blindly use `std::shared_ptr`. Many times when developers jump straight to `std::shared_ptr` it is because they don't have a clear idea of what object *actually* is supposed to own that memory. Much of the time, there is a single object that is responsible for the memory ownership, therefore `std::unique_ptr` is the applicable choice in those cases.

Comment: Start with `unique_ptr`.  It is trivial to change it to `shared_ptr` later on.

Comment: Generally speaking, functions don't need to own their parameters, so you shouldn't be defaulting to passing pointers around

Comment: Maybe are they overusing shared pointer passing around something should be passed by const reference instead?

Comment: My thoughts : if you can't decide on what kind of pointer to write, then it is a sign the main problem is that there is no clear architectural design/insight.

That being said, shared_ptr cause overhead indeed and there is a mighty risk for cyclic reference counting, causing memory leaks. Go for a garbage collector instead if you really have trouble deciding.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a wrapper object, just an alias

```
using FooPtr = std::unique_ptr<Foo>;
```

and then use `FooPtr` throughout.

Often you don't need pointers *at all*. Consider returning `Foo`, `const Foo &` or `Foo &`.

Comment: @LewisChan many objects whose ownership you have to pass around?